# How set null to first option in Laravel 5 blade

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

here is laravel blade selectyears which generates select from 2013 to 2015  and need set first option to null.

```
{!! Form::selectYear('year', 2013, 2015) !!}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have another array `array(''=>"Select Year")` in your select

I guess that you need null because you might need to place some text like `Select Year` like that.

Here is What you need

```
{!! Form::select('year', range(2013, 2015) + array(''=>"Select Year")) !!}
```