# Autocomplete js placeholder is not working with Form::select laravel 4

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using laravel 4 and autocomplete 1.2.21 (https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

```
 {{ Form::select('port',$port,null, array('class'=>'form-control combo','id'=>'port','placeholder'=>'Select Port')) }}
```

Getting the placeholder with laravel 5 but **not in 4** can some one help me with this.

So I see the first array of $port to be selected, I don't need default value to be selected I need a placeholder saying Select Port.

Is there any way without passing **Select Port** and having it as disabled and selected in loop.

Comment: I don't think that attr placeholder can be use on select tag. Use a default option instead.

Comment: Probably duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709528/how-set-null-to-first-option-in-laravel-5-blade)

Comment: Yes it works with the link, I am getting this error with Laravel 4 for laravel 5 its works with placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

On referring some article I got it done with this
(array('' => 'Select Port') + $port) and selected

**Laravel 4**

```
{{ Form::select('port',(array('' => 'Select Port') + $port),null, array('class'=>'form-control combo','id'=>'port', 'selected')) }}
```

**Laravel 5**

```
{{ Form::select('port',$port,null, array('class'=>'form-control combo','id'=>'port','placeholder'=>'Select Port')) }}
```